# Broken (invalid?) link in the [church-encoding] tag

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

I happened upon the [church-encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/church-encoding) tag which features a link to a supposedly free book.

> [An Introduction To Functional Programming Through Lambda Calculus](http://cs.fit.edu/~ryan/library/functional_programming/gjm.lambook88.pdf) by Greg Michaelson

However, the link leads to a 403 Forbidden page for that resource.

I tried googling the book to see if I could find a substitute link but I couldn't find a free version of the book. I admit, I didn't look too hard but I am also not familiar with the subject matter or which sources would be good. In addition, since I failed finding a free version even after brief searching, I wonder if the book is still free - perhaps that's not the case any more. That is something that I'm again not sure how to verify.

I hope somebody who is more familiar with the situation would be able to either provide a working link to a free copy or, if the book is not free, then the link can be taken down.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I edited the tag wiki and removed the link to that book. That particular tag wiki had more problems. The excerpt was plagiarized from Wikipedia. So I rolled that one back too.

Henceforth if you find an issue in any tag wiki, feel free to improve it by suggesting an edit. You can click on the [Edit Tag Info] button to do that. This will put your edit suggestion in the suggested edits review queue. Once you reach 20k reputation, you can directly edit those tag wikis without waiting for the queue to review your edit.

Comment: The problem is that I was completely out of my depth there, so I wasn't sure if removing the link was the correct option or not. As it turns out, it wasn't as it needed to be removed. So, thank you for the prompt action.

Comment: ...re-read my comment and now I facepalm. "*As it turns out, it wasn't as **THE DESCRIPTION** needed to be removed*" is what I meant. Right now it looks like I'm saying that removing the link is the wrong approach because the link should have been removed...

Comment: Heh, no worries. I could kinda make out that you were missing a couple of words.

Comment: Mainly commented because I couldn't edit the old comment and I was sure somebody else would be confused. Honestly, I myself went "wtf am I saying here?" just by reading my own comment.

Comment: I have taken a stab at a new excerpt. The story of that excerpt isn't pretty. As awkward as its original revision might have been, it didn't constitute plagiarism. Then, an edit removing the sliver of attribution it had [was approved](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7340365).

Comment: @duplode, adding just a mention that it is copied from wikipedia isn't valid attribution. The edit was still a plagiarism (according /help/referencing)

Comment: @BhargavRao I agree it wasn't adequate attribution. Still, the later edit made things far worse, by completely omitting the source and, in the process, making it harder for passers-by to notice the excerpt was problematic.

Answer (score 2):

You can find it free via: [http://www.macs.hw.ac.uk/~greg/books/](http://www.macs.hw.ac.uk/%7Egreg/books/)
but the quality isn't brilliant.